# Rtabmap with Multiple RealSense ZR300 cameras

Tags: slam, navigation, realsense, multiple, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am wondering how can I run Rtabmap for mapping using two RealSense ZR300 cameras on ROS platform. It can run with the standalone Rtabmap using single camera, but when it comes to two cameras, I do not know how to write the launch file. Can anyone provide with some hints? Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271347/rtabmap-with-multiple-realsense-zr300-cameras/) by [Cole](https://answers.ros.org/users/18875/cole/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2017-09-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2017-09-22**:
Here is a [demo launch file](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/3e709d23fc695aa9cb4d97c086132dec05fa24c7/launch/demo/demo_two_kinects.launch) for rtabmapping with 2 kinects. It may help you-, rtabmap supports currently not more than 2 rgbd cameras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could not test with two cameras as I have only one, but the launch file would look like below, based on this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/HandHeldMapping) for ZR300 and the referred [demo launch file](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/3e709d23fc695aa9cb4d97c086132dec05fa24c7/launch/demo/demo_two_kinects.launch) for kinect2:

```
<launch>
   
  <!-- Multi-cameras demo with 2 ZR300 -->

  <!-- Choose visualization -->
  <arg name="rviz"       default="false" />
  <arg name="rtabmapviz" default="true" /> 
  
  <!-- Cameras -->
  <include file="$(find realsense_camera)/launch/zr300_nodelet_rgdb.launch">
    <arg name="camera" value="camera1" />
    <arg name="serial_no" value="1111111111" />
  </include>

  <include file="$(find realsense_camera)/launch/zr300_nodelet_rgdb.launch">
    <arg name="camera" value="camera2" />
    <arg name="serial_no" value="2222222222" />
  </include>

  <!-- Frames: Cameras are placed at 90 degrees, clockwise -->
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_camera1_tf"
      args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /camera1_link 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_camera2_tf"
      args="-0.1325 -0.1975 0.0 -1.570796327 0.0 0.0 /base_link /camera2_link 100" />
      
   <!-- sync rgb/depth images per camera -->
   <group ns="camera1">
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager1" args="manager"/>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_to_depthimage1" args="load rtabmap_ros/pointcloud_to_depthimage nodelet_manager1">
      <remap from="cloud"           to="depth/points"/>           <!-- input -->
      <remap from="camera_info"     to="rgb/camera_info"/>        <!-- input -->
      <remap from="image_raw"       to="depth/points/image_raw"/> <!-- output 16bits -->
      <remap from="image"           to="depth/points/image"/>     <!-- output 32bits -->
      <param name="approx"          value="false"/>
      <param name="fill_holes_size" value="2"/>
    </node>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="rgbd_sync1" args="load rtabmap_ros/rgbd_sync nodelet_manager1">
      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="rgb/image_rect_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="depth/points/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="rgb/camera_info"/>
      <param name="approx"          value="false"/>
    </node>
   </group>
   <group ns="camera2">
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="nodelet_manager2" args="manager"/>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_to_depthimage2" args="load rtabmap_ros/pointcloud_to_depthimage nodelet_manager2">
      <remap from="cloud"           to="depth/points"/>           <!-- input -->
      <remap from="camera_info"     to="rgb/camera_info"/>        <!-- input -->
      <remap from="image_raw"       to="depth/points/image_raw"/> <!-- output 16bits -->
      <remap from="image"           to="depth/points/image"/>     <!-- output 32bits -->
      <param name="approx"          value="false"/>
      <param name="fill_holes_size" value="2"/>
    </node>
    <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="rgbd_sync2" args="load rtabmap_ros/rgbd_sync nodelet_manager2">
      <remap from="rgb/image"       to="rgb/image_rect_color"/>
      <remap from="depth/image"     to="depth/points/image_raw"/>
      <remap from="rgb/camera_info" to="rgb/camera_info"/>
      <param name="approx"          value="false"/>
    </node>
   </group>
        
  <group ns="rtabmap">
  
    <!-- Odometry -->
    <node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odometry" output="screen">
      <remap from="rgbd_image0"       to="/camera1/rgbd_image"/>
      <remap from="rgbd_image1"       to="/camera2/rgbd_image"/>
      
      <param name="subscribe_rgbd"           type="bool"   value="true"/>
      <param name="frame_id"                 type="string" value="base_link"/>
      <param name="rgbd_cameras"             type="int"    value="2"/>
      <param name="Vis/EstimationType"       type="string" value="0"/> <!-- should be 0 for multi-cameras -->
    </node>
  
    <!-- Visual SLAM (robot side) -->
    <!-- args: "delete_db_on_start" and "udebug" -->
    <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start">
      <param name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool"   value="false"/>
      <param name="subscribe_rgbd"   type="bool"   value="true"/>
      <param name="rgbd_cameras"     type="int"    value="2"/>
      <param name="frame_id"         type="string" value="base_link"/>
      <param name="gen_scan"         type="bool"   value="true"/>
      <param name="map_negative_poses_ignored" type="bool"   value="false"/>        <!-- refresh grid map even if we are not moving-->
      <param name="map_negative_scan_empty_ray_tracing" type="bool" value="false"/> <!-- don't fill empty space between the generated scans-->
    
      <remap from="rgbd_image0"       to="/camera1/rgbd_image"/>
      <remap from="rgbd_image1"       to="/camera2/rgbd_image"/>

      <param name="Grid/FromDepth"     type="string" value="false"/>
      <param name="Vis/EstimationType" type="string" value="0"/> <!-- should be 0 for multi-cameras -->
    </node>
  
    <!-- Visualisation RTAB-Map -->
    <node if="$(arg rtabmapviz)" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmapviz" name="rtabmapviz" args="-d $(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbd_gui.ini" output="screen">
      <param name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool"   value="false"/>
      <param name="subscribe_rgbd"   type="bool"   value="true"/>
      <param name="subscribe_odom_info" type="bool"   value="true"/>
      <param name="frame_id"            type="string" value="base_link"/>
      <param name="rgbd_cameras"       type="int"    value="2"/>
    
      <remap from="rgbd_image0"       to="/camera1/rgbd_image"/>
      <remap from="rgbd_image1"       to="/camera2/rgbd_image"/>
    </node>
  
  </group>
  
  <!-- Visualization RVIZ -->
  <node if="$(arg rviz)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbd.rviz"/>

</launch>
```

You will have to modify the serial number of the cameras, update the static transforms between the cameras and the base, then:

```
$ roslaunch test.launch
```

Note that rtabmap >=Kinetic can support up to 4 cameras.

cheers,

Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thibs-sigma](https://answers.ros.org/users/40527/thibs-sigma/) on 2019-03-19**:
Hi Mathieu,

I know, it has been a while since this post was created, but today, I'm facing the same issue.

I would like to perform V-SLAM mapping thanks to RTAB-MAP, with two D435 cameras. I tried to adapt the code you posted just above, but nothing happens in RTAB-MAP. Maybe the code is not adapted to the new versions of RTAB-MAP?

I precise that everything is working well with only one D435 camera (with the `rs-rgbd.launch` file).

Many thanks for your help,

Cheers,

Thibaud

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2019-03-22**:
You may post a new question with the detailed launch file you use. For realsense2, you may not use `rtabmap_ros/pointcloud_to_depthimage` nodelets for example, as you can have the depth directly. the rest is remapping the correct image topics to `rgbd_sync` nodelets, and maybe change the `frame_id` used.

**Comment by [thibs-sigma](https://answers.ros.org/users/40527/thibs-sigma/) on 2019-03-25**:
I am sorry about that...
But thanks, just as you said, remapping and avoiding the use of nodelets, I succeeded in launching mapping with two D435 cameras.

**Comment by [Corey_Cazes](https://answers.ros.org/users/40563/corey_cazes/) on 2019-04-09**:
Hey Thibs-sigma, I am pretty much trying to accomplish the exact same thing as you. Could you maybe post your remapped file for the D435 cameras somewhere. I'm having trouble remapping myself and this would help me a ton!

**Comment by [thibs-sigma](https://answers.ros.org/users/40527/thibs-sigma/) on 2019-04-10**:
Hi Corey Cazes,
You can find my launch file working with 3 D435 [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thibs-sigma/-KTH-2019-FACT-Project/master/03-MULTICAMERA-MAPPING/multi_D435.launch?token=AmGcz8Yy7Rv-9NO_Ebt4ppLy_QwdgK2nks5craUcwA%3D%3D).
Cheers,
Thibaud

**Comment by [Corey_Cazes](https://answers.ros.org/users/40563/corey_cazes/) on 2019-04-10**:
The link doesn't seem to be working

**Comment by [thibs-sigma](https://answers.ros.org/users/40527/thibs-sigma/) on 2019-04-11**:
Sorry, you can actually found it [here](https://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0ISEH9) ;)
Hope this will help you.

**Comment by [garand](https://answers.ros.org/users/43154/garand/) on 2019-06-19**:
Hi thibs-sigma,Can the`"/home/thib/realsenseTests_ws/src/hw_sync/launch/hw_sync.launch"` synchronize 3 d435 in your launch file working with 3 d435？Did you write the launch file yourself?I would appreciate it if you could provide me with this launch file.

**Comment by [samtech](https://answers.ros.org/users/59649/samtech/) on 2020-09-27**:
hi , i need help for running three d 435 cameras with rtabmap , the code given by thibs-sigma doesn't work ..